# Register an alarm in the official "Alarms" list?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm using the `ScheduledActionService` to schedule alarms in my application.  Is it possible to get them to show up in the Alarms application that's listed in the phone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im sorry to say this is not possible in WP7 or WP7.5